# NOT IN is not working as expected with Listagg function

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is the DDL of the table

```
  create or replace table  tempdw.blk_table;
   (
     db_name varchar,
     tbl_expr varchar
   );

   insert into  tempdw.blk_table  values ('edw','ABC%');
   insert into  tempdw.blk_table  values ('edw','EFG%');

   select * from tempdw.blk_table;
```

[image]

Below code is not working, expected output should not return any

```
select * from tempdw.blk_table where tbl_expr not in (
       select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(replace(listagg(tbl_expr,','),',','\',\''),'^','\''),'$','\'') from tempdw.blk_table);
```

When I run below code it works fine , Trying to understand why it's not working for above code

```
select * from tempdw.blk_table where tbl_expr NOT IN('ABC%','EFG%');
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement.  It is not obvious.

Comment: This is not working because building a "string" is not the same as a string passed to the SQL parser.

Answer (score 0):

*Au contraire*  The code is working just fine.  You don't understand the difference between a string that has commas and a list of strings.

Unfortunately, it is rather hard to figure out what you *do* want to do, because your question does not explain that.

I can speculate that you want something like:

```
select bt.*
from blk_table bt
where db_name like tbl_expr;
```

This is just a guess, however.

Comment: I understand a string that has comma and list of strings .. I am first getting a list of strings and ignoring all the  table_expression that is available in the list of strings

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select * from values ('edw','ABC%'),('edw','ABC%') v(db_name,tbl_expr )
)
select * from data 
where tbl_expr not in (
       select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(replace(listagg(tbl_expr,','),',','\',\''),'^','\''),'$','\'') from data);
```

does indeed give the results you don't want. aka:

```
DB_NAME TBL_EXPR
edw ABC%
edw ABC%
```

because your sub-query only has one row of results, because you have aggregated the two input into one row.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( REGEXP_REPLACE( REPLACE( LISTAGG( TBL_EXPR,','),',','\',\''),'^','\''),'$','\'')
 'ABC%','ABC%'
```

and `NOT IN` is a exact match .. thus if we change from strings to numbers:

```
SELECT num, num in (2,3,4) FROM values (1),(3),(5) v(num);
```

gives:

```
 NUM    NUM IN (2,3,4)
 1      0
 3      1
 5      0
```

so your `NOT IN` would only return strings that are not in the list of one you have... and given your list is the aggregate of the same input, that are by definition not that same.

back to strings..

```
SELECT str
    ,str in ('str_a', 'str_b')
    ,str not in ('str_a', 'str_b')
from values ('a'),('str_b') v(str);
```

gives:

```
STR    STR IN ('STR_A', 'STR_B')    STR NOT IN ('STR_A', 'STR_B')
a       0                           1
str_b   1                           0
```

Thus the results you are getting..

now I suspect you are want LIKE type behavior OR a REGEX match, but given you are building the list you know what you are doing there..

also note:

```
listagg(tbl_expr,',') AS a
    ,replace(a,',','\',\'') AS b
    ,regexp_replace(b,'^','\'') AS c
    ,regexp_replace(c,'$','\'') AS d
```

is the effect of what you are doing can be replaced with

```
listagg('\'' || tbl_expr || '\'',',')
```

unless you want strings with embedded comma to become independent "list" items..

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, actually, the table had two different values ... I have updated the original question

Comment: ideally, when I run the below query it shouldn't return values 

              
 ```with data as (
    select * from values ('edw','ABC%'),('edw','EFG%') v(db_name,tbl_expr )
)
select * from data 
where tbl_expr not in (
       select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(replace(listagg(tbl_expr,','),',','\',\''),'^','\''),'$','\'') from data
);```

Comment: the data in your example is not the problem you are asking show me `X when X <> XY` and show me `Y when Y <> XY` given the left hand side is the parts of the input, and the right hand side is the input mushed together, they will never be equal, thus your will see all the input..

Comment: I think I am seeing your gap, `NOT IN('ABC%','EFG%');` is say each value is not in the last of string, the round brackets start/end the list and the comma between the string value, how ever when you build you string, it's a single string. Thus is not a list, now you could make it a list, but that us would defeat the point, because you started with a list, and turned it into a string, why not just use the array you have at the begining, and use ARRAY_AGG

Comment: I have tried with Array_AGG , it doesn't help either 



```SQL compilation error: Can not convert parameter 'ALL(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DATA.TBL_EXPR) AS "ARRAY_AGG(TBL_EXPR)" FROM (SELECT V.COLUMN1 AS "DB_NAME", V.COLUMN2 AS "TBL_EXPR" FROM (VALUES ('edw', 'ABC%'), ('edw', 'EFG%')) V) DATA)' of type [ARRAY] into expected type [VARCHAR(4)]
```

below the code syntax

```sql
with data as (
    select * from values ('edw','ABC%'),('edw','EFG%') v(db_name,tbl_expr )
)
select * from data 
where tbl_expr not in (select array_agg(tbl_expr) from data);
```

Comment: Yes, because you have completely misunderstood the difference between text that is parsed by the SQL parser, and the output of the SQL engine (that is not parsed again).